# Will this compare arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare long string numbers. The number length is between 1 and fifty.  Comparing the length of the strings worked well but if they were equal length it was a bit harder.  I decided to make the strings into arrays, and compare values until they were different.  I think this is a formatting error, but I'm not sure.

```
function compareIntegers(a, b) {
  //coding and coding..
  var aSplit = a.split("")
  var bSplit = b.split("")

if (a.length > b.length){
    return "greater";
}
        if (b.length > a.length){
            return 'less';
        }
if (a.length == b.length){ 
        for (i=0; aSplit.length; i++){
            if (bSplit.indexOf(aSplit[i] ===-1) {
                if (aSplit[i] > bSplit[i]){
                    return 'greater';
                    }
        if (aSplit[i] < bSplit[i]){
            return 'less';
            }
     else return 'equal';
         }
     }
}

}
describe("Basic Tests", function(){ 
it("It should works for basic tests.", function(){

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers("12","13"),"less")

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers("875","799"),"greater")

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers("1000","1000"),"equal")

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers("999","1000"),"less")

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers("123","122"),"greater")

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers(
    "1000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "1000000000000000000000000000000001"),
    "less"
)
Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers(
    "1000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "1000000000000000000000000000000001"),
    "greater"
)

Test.assertEquals(compareIntegers(
    "10000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "1000000000000000000000000000000001"),
    "greater"
)

})})
```

Comment: Please, *please*, indent your code... then you lower the possibility of a syntax error by a ton.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your actual code doesn't begin with `\`enter code here\`` :). Please provide inputs and expected outputs, and what your current code does.

Comment: Your logic sounds safe, but your `if(bSplit.indexOf(aSplit[i] === -1)` may be a problem ;) (also you probably don't need that check, i would just compare from start -> end, and the first difference will tell you if it's greater than or less than)

Comment: `if (bSplit.indexOf(aSplit[i] ===-1)` - missing 1 closing parenthesis

Comment: "Comparing the length of the strings worked well but if they were equal length it was a bit harder" Are you trying to find out if lengths are the same??

Comment: I am trying to figure out if the string  "var a" is greater, equal or less than "var b:.

Comment: You don't have to split: `console.log("1000000" < "1000001");`

Comment: What Casimir et Hippolyte said.  You can compare two numbers directly.  If for some reason they're strings just use something like num = parseInt(str);

Comment: @chairmanmow: absolutely not! I said that you can compare two strings (of the same length) using `<`, `>`, `==`. In this case these operators compare the characters of the string (strings are not casted to int), but since the digits are ordered in the ascii table, it returns the good result.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I misunderstood what you were trying to say about two strings of the same length.  Even if they weren't the same length, wouldn't you just be able to parseInt() and compare assuming they contain numeric characters?

Comment: Make sure you test this case too: `"100" < "20" --> true`

Comment: the only problem with that is that for numbers longer than 15 digits.  because javascript is 64 bit rounds up or down.  so I get values like this    a = "935733785600167217170222696231886"
b = "935733785600167217170222696231885" 
Expected: 'greater', instead got: 'equal'

Comment: @chairmanmow: Brett Davis anwsered for me. The final goal of this is to deal with big integers.

Comment: @BrettDavis JavaScript *numbers* are limited to 64 bit (51 bit integer) precision. Your `a` and `b` values are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to split the strings into arrays, you can easily access the single characters using an index property or `.charAt()`. And there's no reason to do this character-by-character comparison by yourself at all (and making mistakes like `bSplit.indexOf(aSplit[i])`), when that is just the default behaviour of comparing two strings. So I'd write

```
function compareIntegerStrings(a, b) {
  a = a.replace(/^0*/, ""); // strip leading zeroes
  b = b.replace(/^0*/, "");

  if (a.length > b.length){
    return 1;
  } else if (b.length > a.length){
    return -1;
  } else { // a.length == b.length
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else if (b > a) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
function comparisonToString(c) {
  return ['less', 'equal', 'greater'][Math.sign(c)];
}
```

You can also shorten that comparison pyramid in `compareIntegerStrings` to

```
return Math.sign(a.length - b.length) || +(a>b) || -(a<b);
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  Because of long strings (greater than 15 characters) it calls two similar numbers == when they are clearly not.

Comment: @BrettDavis Are you doing this with numbers or with strings? Did you initially use `parseInt` somewhere?

Comment: the inputs are strings.  instead of parseInt, I used Number.  Had the same problem.

Comment: Well yes, `Number` does cast the string to a number. That is now what you want, you have to compare the strings to get character-by-character comparison! Please try the code in my answer, it will work for arbitrarily long sequences of digits.